# Getting orientation without using UIApplication.delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

In one of my view controllers, I do this...

```
self.gridCamera.orientation = motion.gaze(atOrientation: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation)
```

The function returns a SCNVector4 that aligns a SceneKit view with the proper "up".

`UIApplication.shared` is no longer allowed from outside the main thread. Instead of just calling it from a `dispatch`, can anyone suggest a different way to do it entirely? Is there a better way to get the orientation that isn't reliant on the `UIApplication.shared`?

Comment: Why not use [UIDeviceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation)?

Comment: @Dopapp - yeah I can do that, but I'm just curious if I'm missing some canonical way to do this by using this call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UIDeviceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation) seems to be reliant on [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice), which provides a representation of the current device.

> Returns the physical orientation of the device.

---

[This blog](https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/ios-using-uideviceorientation-to-determine-orientation/) will help you on how to use UIDeviceOrientation to determine the applications orientation.

> Using *UIDeviceOrientation* may not be the best way to get the
>   orientation of the views, but sometimes this is still needed.
>   Following this guide should help you get started, and most of the
>   time, this is all you will need. Just be sure to read through the
>   important points. Drop by in the comments section if this post helped.

Comment: That is precisely what I was wondering about. I've updated my code to use this instead. Thanks!